# Install GitHub dependency using PNPM in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, github, pnpm

I'm using `pnpm` in `Dockerfile` I have one dependency which is installed from **GitHub**.
PNPM by default use `yarn` to install dependency from Git.
Problem with PNPM is it is not able to access the yarn, I think some kind of permission problem.

> **ERROR:**
> ERR_PNPM_PREPARE_PKG_FAILURE  Command failed with exit code 1: /usr/local/bin/yarn install
> The command '/bin/sh -c pnpm install' returned a non-zero code: 1

Here is my **Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:alpine

RUN npm install -g pnpm

WORKDIR /app

COPY ["package.json", "pnpm-lock.yaml", "./"]

RUN pnpm install

COPY . .

RUN pnpm build

ENV PORT=8080

EXPOSE 80

CMD [ "node", "./build/index.js" ]
```

**Update**

This is repo that is used from GitHub. [Baileys](https://github.com/adiwajshing/Baileys)

Everything works perfect when I try to install packages without **Dockerfile** If I run `pnpm install` everything just works. But When I run the build command for Dockerfile it will create problem.
`docker build -t name .`

Comment: I can't reproduce with a simple dependency from GitHub: `"isarray": "github:juliangruber/isarray"` in my `package.json` dependencies. Is [that issue](https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm/issues/4374) related? Does your GitHub dependency have lifecycle scripts?

Comment: I'm using this repo [Baileys](https://github.com/adiwajshing/Baileys)

Comment: **Check update** it only problem when I build docker image otherwise install packages `pnpm install` work fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you stated, `pnpm` uses `yarn` to install dependencies from Git. From your output, you can see that `yarn` failed. If you run inside Docker container `yarn add https://github.com/adiwajshing/Baileys.git`, it would output:

```
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
error Couldn't find the binary git
```

`node:alpine` image is missing `git`.

---

To resolve your problem, simply install `git` before `pnpm install` in `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache git
RUN npm install -g pnpm
...
```